# Is it possible to specify a port in a ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use jQuery to run an AJAX query on a specific port:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
        url: "http://test_serve:666/test.php",

        type: "GET",
        data: ({value_test: 'true'}),
        dataType: "html"

    });
})
```

This doesn't work: no AJAX call is made and I don't get any exceptions in Firebug.
It does work if I don't specify the port. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't work due the [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). AJAX requests are allowed only in the same domain, protocol and port.

If you really need to get data from that source, you should look forward to JSONP.

Answer (score 1):

is the webpage you use that is on the same port ?

If not you would run into the [**same origin policy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and it won't work.