# jQuery Ajax on Different Port

Tags: php, ajax

My php file located at port 80 (default port) while my ajax call are on port 8080.

My index.html on port 8080

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.get("userCheck.php", 
        {"username" : "lazy", "favcolor" : "FFFFFF" },          
        function(data){ alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

My PHP

```
$user = $_GET["username"];
if($user == "lazy")
    echo "SUCESS";
else
    echo "FAIL";
```

I have googled abit, JSONP came out mostly. Any idea how to convert it to JSONP?

Any way to make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768385/jquery-is-it-possible-to-specif-a-port-in-a-ajax-call

Comment: do u use http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing a JSONP service is really simple, you need only a *callback* GET parameter and at the end, print a string containing the equivalent to a function call with the JSON data as the argument:

```
$callback = $_GET["callback"];
$user = $_GET["username"];

if($user == "lazy") {
  $response = array("message" => "SUCESS");
} else {
  $response = array("message" => "FAIL");
}

echo $callback . "(". json_encode($response) . ");";
```

Then you can use it with jQuery [`$.getJSON`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON):

```
$.getJSON("jsonpTest.php?callback=?", { username: "lazy"}, function(json){
  alert("JSON Data: " + json.message); // SUCCESS
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You could try creating a full URL with a port number (`http://myserver:[port]/userCheck.php`), but **it won't work**. ([Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy))

Performing a query on a different port is not something you should use JSONP for, because any good JSONP framework would block that (or at least it should). It's not the primary goal of JSONP to allow these things, it's only a side-effect from the implementation.

But you can create a **"facade" PHP script** on the same port as `index.html`, which then performs the query to the different URL and returns the value. This way the browser does not know about the real URL.

`index.html (8080) <--> myAjaxFacade.php (8080) <--> userCheck.php (80)`

To do this you could use the **[http-post-fields](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-post-fields.php)** function, for example.

**Example:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.get("myAjaxFacade.php", 
    {"username" : "lazy", "favcolor" : "FFFFFF", 
     "realUrl": "http://serverwithdifferent:port/userCheck.php" },          
    function(data){ alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

In `myAjaxFacade.php` then forward all other POST data to `$_POST['realUrl']` and return the response from that URL.

Comment: no go, since i got around like 50 ports on 8080 - 8130. and those port are come from external source software(not apache).

Comment: You can just provide the port as a parameter to the proxy script, you don't have to use 50 scripts :)

Comment: can you give me example? i'm not sure how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: Where do i store myAjaxFacade.php, sorry.

Comment: On your server, where the index.html is.

Comment: Those port are come from external source software(not apache) and only output HTML. 

I cannot store php on there.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot do that because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Since the port are different the same origin policy would apply and block your XHR call.

You would have to use a proxy to do such things, you can take a look at [JsonP](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/) or build your own proxy using curl or copy your code to be on the same port.

Answer (score 1):

The [Same Origin Policy (SOP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) denies Javascript from sending requests to any other host and port than the one it was downloaded from.

What is needed to work around this is a programm running on the same host and port as the origin of the javascript that forwards requests to the the actual service. A program that acts like this is commonly called a *proxy*, so what is needed is a *JSONP proxy*.

If your server was running **ruby/rails and sinatra**, [github.com/greenisus/jsonp-proxy](https://github.com/greenisus/jsonp-proxy)  would be a minimal solution. A solution for **PHP** that seems to have many features would be [benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/](http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/).

Answer (score 0):

For JSONP on PHP, see the example [here](http://www.carolinamantis.com/wordpress/?p=29). You add a "callback" parameter to the URL specifying a function name to run, and in your PHP code make sure to emit JavaScript that call's the callback with the data. jQuery injects a script element with your content - when it runs it calls the callback.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution could be by deploying 'HAProxy' or 'socat'. They can reroute the request to a different port.