# Javascript vb2013 calling url removing host name

Tags: javascript, url

I am new to serious javascript programming, Working my way up in the world to HTML5 and I have gone round and round.

The address works in a browser so I know its there, but when I go to debug I get a `404` error from the following javascript code

```
function loadTotalLabels() {
    //get json data
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ "args": "" });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        url:"http://localhost:52594/Service1.svc/getTest",
        data: jsonData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json", // dataType is json format
        success: onTotalsSuccess_,
        error: OnErrorCall_
    });
}
```

When I look at the error it tells me that it can not find `Service1.svc/getTest`

If I remove the Port number and put the project name in (http://localhost/prsTest/service1.svc/getTest which is running on my local IIS), it works fine (throws a Network error, but one error at a time).

So, can anyone tell me how to get the Javascript to use the "localhost + port number"?  I have tried `location.host` and that did not work.  Or tell me where to look, as I have not found anything on this item.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768385/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-port-in-a-ajax-call  Might be helpful

Comment: Thank you, it is annoying, but if that is the way it has to be.  I will move it to the local IIS server, and just run it off of there.   Thank you qwerty_igor.