# IBM MobileFirst - Call WS REST created with IBM RAD

Tags: web-services, rest, jax-rs, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-rad

I have an application in MobileFirst, and use an ajax function to call REST WS created with IBM RAD, this is the AJAX function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:9080/myproject/rest/helloworld/",
    contentType: "text/plain",
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
            var sHelloWorld = response;
            $("#prueba").empty();
            $("#prueba").append(sHelloWorld); 
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert('ERROR ' + result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
    }
});
```

But I get error

> "Access Denied result.status = 0"

Could you be related to this article?
[Is it possible to specify a port in a ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768385/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-port-in-a-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have likely created a mobile web app (Android, iOS, etc...), note that you're pointing to *localhost*. That means that your AJAX request is pointing to the *device* and not to an actual destination.

Replace "localhost" with the IP address of the backend you are attempting to connect to.

Comment: Just an fyi, if using an Android emulator, change localhost to 10.0.2.2 as specified by Android Emulator docs 
http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking